# MS Teams - how to hide everyone but one screen

Tags: microsoft-teams

My daughter is remote schooling via MS Teams.

She is able to see a video of each person on the call (teacher and other students).

This is distracting and we would rather she only saw the teacher.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simply hover over any video, click the 3 white dots and pin the video.

It doesn't hide the other videos but does make them massively smaller and less distracting.

Comment: What quote on that 8 page thread is relevant?  I would rather not have to read all 8 pages to determine that myself.